# What is data context in UWP?

Tags: data-binding, uwp, uwp-xaml, datacontext

```
public string Name
{
    get
    {
        return this.name;
    }
    set
    {
        this.name = value;
    }
}
```

here this is equivalent to

```
public string Name{ get; set; } right?
```

similarly for the class variable

```
public NewsItem ns { get { return this.DataContext as  NewsItem; } }
```

and

```
public NewsItem ns{get;}
```

are they same????
if not what will the default return value in  public NewsItem ns{get;}

and what does that this.DataContext means in

```
public NewsItem ns { get { return this.DataContext as  NewsItem; } }
```

what will be the return value if the code is like this

```
public NewsItem ns { get { return this.DataContext} }
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

> difference between `public string Name{ get; set; }` and  `public string Name{ get { return name; }...`

In C# 3.0 and later, (the previous one)[**auto-implemented properties**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties) make property-declaration more concise when no additional logic is required in the property accessors. They also enable client code to create objects. And the last one is a normal [**property**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) that is a member that provides a flexible mechanism to read, write, or compute the value of a private field.

> public NewsItem ns { get { return this.DataContext as  NewsItem; } }

The [`DataContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.datacontext?view=winrt-20348) for a FrameworkElement. A common use of a data context is when a FrameworkElement uses the {Binding} markup extension and participates in data binding. If you want to DataContext could be regarded as `NewsItem`. you need pass NewsItem instance to DataContext, when page  initialize.

```
public TestPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = new NewsItem();
}
```

> what will be the return value if the code is like this `public NewsItem ns { get { return this.DataContext} }`

please refer to above description, if you call `ns` get method it will return a NewsItem instance that was evaluated current `DataContext`.

Comment: Zhu
 Hai, if this. data context is not assigned initially  and what would be the return values for these
```
public NewsItem ns { get { return this.DataContext ; } }
```
```
public NewsItem ns { get ; }
```

Comment: if you have not assigned value for DataContext, it will return null when you call NewsItem  get method.

Answer (score 0):

Your first `Name` property returns the value of the `name` field. The second is an auto-implented property that returns the value of a compiler generated field value that you don't see in your code. They are not equivalent.

`public NewsItem ns { get { return this.DataContext as  NewsItem; } }` returns the current value of the `DataContext` property *if*  it has been set to a `NewsItem` value. Otherwise it returns `null`.

`public NewsItem ns {get;}` returns the current value of the `ns` property which will be `null` unless you have explicitly set it to some value somewhere. So they are not the same.

So to answer your question, the default value of the `DataContext` property is `null` so you have to set it in order to be able to bind to some property of it.

It's not set for you by the framework, unless it's inherited from a parent element in the visual tree.